# Why can VAO use VBO data whthout bind it?

Tags: c++, opengl

Why VAO can use VBO data without binding it?

https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing
i find it from this webpage. 
the code page:
https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/4.advanced_opengl/10.3.asteroids_instanced/asteroids_instanced.cpp

```cpp
    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount * sizeof(glm::mat4), &modelMatrices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rock.meshes.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned int VAO = rock.meshes[i].VAO;
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        // set attribute pointers for matrix (4 times vec4)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec4)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
        glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)(2 * sizeof(glm::vec4)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
        glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)(3 * sizeof(glm::vec4)));

        glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

the rock.meshes[i].VAO use the buffer data without bind it?
i think it should be this：

```cpp
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rock.meshes.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned int VAO = rock.meshes[i].VAO;
        GLuint buffer;
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount * sizeof(glm::mat4), &modelMatrices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ......
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `buffer` is still bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.
OpenGL is a state engine, and the last instruction which binds a buffer object to the the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` was:

> ```
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
> ```

So `buffer` is still bound when you do the definition of generic vertex attribute data.

When the array of generic vertex attribute data is specified (`glVertexAttribPointer`), then the vertex specification (index, tuple size, format, stride, offset, ...) and the "name" of the current buffer object, which is bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, is set to the [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) state vector.
See [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object).

Note, an [Index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) would be stated in the Vertex Array Object directly. So the Vertex Array Object has to be bound, before a buffer is bound to the target `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Binding a buffer object to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` does **not** change the the current Vertex Array Object's states, but binding a buffer object to the target `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` modifies the VAOs states.

A Vertex Array Object can refer to only one index buffer, but it can refer to a separate array buffer for each attribute.